# How to change front camera angle to wide?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

[image][image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V060T.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjtgU.jpg)

I wonder what the function of the button at the bottom of the front camera is.

I also changed the deviceType to implement this function, but it didn't change.

Exactly what values should I change for this function to get the result?

Comment: The front camera has a fixed focal length.  The "Wide/zoom" setting is just in software - a section of the image is cropped.

Comment: @Paulw11
At first, I thought the image was cropped and I thought I could use it, but when I checked the imageBuffer value coming from AVCaptureSession, I found that it only came over like a left screenshot from the above screenshot.

What I'm curious about is that the iPhone system camera is showing a wider image than the AVCaptureSession.

Comment: And I always use the zoom factor value as 1.0. This means I connot zoom-out anymore.

Comment: I found answer.
Using AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo.

Comment: @JunHyeonKim can you elaborate more on your solution?

Comment: @AcidicSkittles
When you use the camera, you will set the sessionPreset of the AVCaptureSession, and you can set this value to AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo.